# How to display information from a file on the Internet in textview

Tags: android

Need help, there is a document which is at a similar link http://url.com/info.xsl

It has the following structure:

```
<data>
      <Connections/>
            <Current_Listeners>3</Current_Listeners>
            <Description/>
            <Currently_Playing>
                   <Name>Black Sun Empire - Salvador (Feat. Bless)</Name>
            </Currently_Playing>
            <Source/>
      <Connections/>
      <Current_Listeners>0</Current_Listeners>
      <Description/>
            <Currently_Playing>
                   <Name>Black Sun Empire - Salvador (Feat. Bless)</Name>
            </Currently_Playing>
      <Source/>
</data>
```

How can I read the file to select the information from the box between the tags  , and display it in my TextView.

Comment: u mean u want to read particular node and display in textview???

Comment: You can use xml parsing

Comment: I want to read a line between the tags and display it

Comment: this one <Currently_Playing> ???

Comment: Will the XML parsing file with XSL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like that :

```
            // Get your file from internet
    URL url = new URL("http://url.com/info.xsl");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/filename.xml"
    File file = new File (filePath);

    CreateFileFromInputStream(in,  filePath) ;

            // Parse it with document builder factory
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder dBuilder = null;
    dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = null;
    doc = dBuilder.parse(file);
    doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
    // The root element is 
    doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();

    NodeList nList =    doc.getElementsByTagName("Name");

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < nList.getLength() ; i++ ) {

        Element element = (Element) nList.item(i) ;
        String name = getCharacterDataFromElement(element);

    }
```

with :

```
public static String getCharacterDataFromElement(Element e)
{
    Node node = e.getFirstChild();
    if (node instanceof CharacterData)
    {
        CharacterData cd = (CharacterData) node;
        return cd.getData();
    }
    return "";
}
```

and :

```
public void CreateFileFromInputStream(InputStream inStream, String path) throws IOException {
    // write the inputStream to a FileOutputStream
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));

    int read = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

    while ((read = inStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        out.write(bytes, 0, read);
    }

    inStream.close();
    out.flush();
    out.close();

}
```

I hope it helps ...

Comment: Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable shows on nList here for ( Node node : nList ) {

Comment: Ok, i didn't remember that NodeList wasn't iterable. I edited my questions, i replaced the foreach by a for

Comment: Thank you very much, had a little to finish did not want to load on the line had to be done through AsyncTask and add a line to the manifest for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE